# perl printing in wrong format

Tags: perl

I have a `perl` code segment to produce parse trees from input text but it produces wrongly formated parse trees. I need to produce the `(` `)` and `S` brackets according to number of 
suffix and prefix and stem.

Code>

```
use strict;
use warnings qw/ all FATAL /;
use List::Util 'reduce';

# our ($a, $b);

while ( <> ) {
    chomp;
    my ($word, $ss) = split ' ', $_, 2;   
    my @ss = split /\s/, $ss;

    my $str = reduce { sprintf 'S (%s) (%s)', $a, $b } @ss;

    printf "%s (%s)\n", $word, $str;
}
```

Input

```
 (অংশগ্রহণও)      (অংশ:stem গ্রহণ:suffix ও:suffix ) 
 (অংশজুড়েই)   (অংশ:stem জুড়ে:suffix ই:suffix ) 
 (অংশত্ব)     (অংশ:stem ত্ব:suffix ) 
 (অংশসহ)      (অংশ:stem সহ:suffix ) 
 (অংশীদারত্বে)    (অংশ:stem ী:suffix দার:suffix ত্ব:suffix ে:suffix ) 
 (অকল্পনীয়)   (অ:prefix কল্প:suffix নীয়:suffix ) 
 (অকাণ্ড)     (অ:prefix কাণ্ড:suffix ) 
 (অক্টোবর)    (অক্টোবর) 
 (অক্টোবরে)   (অক্টোবর:stem ে:suffix ) 
 (অখাদ্যে)    (অ:prefix খাদ্য:suffix ে:suffix ) 
 (অগণিত)      (অ:prefix গণিত:suffix ) 
 (অগ্নিগোলা)      (অগ্নি:stem গোলা:suffix ) 
 (অগ্নিনির্বাপণের)    (অগ্নি:stem নির্বাপণ:suffix ের:suffix ) 
 (অগ্নিপরীক্ষা)   (অগ্নি:stem পরীক্ষা:suffix ) 
 (অগ্নিসংযোগসহ)   (অগ্নি:stem সংযোগ:suffix সহ:suffix )
```

Expected output>

```
অগ্নিসংযোগসহ      (S(S(অগ্নি:stem) (সংযোগ:suffix)) (সহ:suffix ))
```

It produces wrong output. In the produced output, you could see  many errors, for example : `()`

```
 (অংশ) ((অংশ))
    (অংশগ্রহণও) (S (S (S ((অংশ:stem) (গ্রহণ:suffix)) (ও:suffix)) ()))
    (অংশজুড়েই) (S (S (S ((অংশ:stem) (জুড়ে:suffix)) (ই:suffix)) ()))
    (অংশত্ব) (S (S ((অংশ:stem) (ত্ব:suffix)) ()))
    (অংশসহ) (S (S ((অংশ:stem) (সহ:suffix)) ()))
    (অংশীদারত্বে) (S (S (S (S (S ((অংশ:stem) (ী:suffix)) (দার:suffix)) (ত্ব:suffix)) (ে:suffix)) ()))
    (অকল্পনীয়) (S (S (S ((অ:prefix) (কল্প:suffix)) (নীয়:suffix)) ()))
    (অকাণ্ড) (S (S ((অ:prefix) (কাণ্ড:suffix)) ()))
    (অক্টোবর) ((অক্টোবর))
    (অক্টোবরে) (S (S ((অক্টোবর:stem) (ে:suffix)) ()))
    (অখাদ্যে) (S (S (S ((অ:prefix) (খাদ্য:suffix)) (ে:suffix)) ()))
    (অগণিত) (S (S ((অ:prefix) (গণিত:suffix)) ()))
```

How can I produce results in expected format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have split the original lines wrongly. I know a little Bengali but I don't know the syntax of the files you're processing

I think it's as simple as extracting all parenthesis-delimited substrings from the source data, like this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use List::Util 'reduce';

while ( <> ) {

    my ($word, $ss) = / \( ( [^()]* ) \) /gx;

    my @ss = split ' ', $ss;

    my $str = reduce { sprintf 'S (%s) (%s)', $a, $b } @ss;

    printf "%s (%s)\n", $word, $str;
}
```

#### output

```
অংশগ্রহণও (S (S (অংশ:stem) (গ্রহণ:suffix)) (ও:suffix))
অংশজুড়েই (S (S (অংশ:stem) (জুড়ে:suffix)) (ই:suffix))
অংশত্ব (S (অংশ:stem) (ত্ব:suffix))
অংশসহ (S (অংশ:stem) (সহ:suffix))
অংশীদারত্বে (S (S (S (S (অংশ:stem) (ী:suffix)) (দার:suffix)) (ত্ব:suffix)) (ে:suffix))
অকল্পনীয় (S (S (অ:prefix) (কল্প:suffix)) (নীয়:suffix))
অকাণ্ড (S (অ:prefix) (কাণ্ড:suffix))
অক্টোবর (অক্টোবর)
অক্টোবরে (S (অক্টোবর:stem) (ে:suffix))
অখাদ্যে (S (S (অ:prefix) (খাদ্য:suffix)) (ে:suffix))
অগণিত (S (অ:prefix) (গণিত:suffix))
অগ্নিগোলা (S (অগ্নি:stem) (গোলা:suffix))
অগ্নিনির্বাপণের (S (S (অগ্নি:stem) (নির্বাপণ:suffix)) (ের:suffix))
অগ্নিপরীক্ষা (S (অগ্নি:stem) (পরীক্ষা:suffix))
অগ্নিসংযোগসহ (S (S (অগ্নি:stem) (সংযোগ:suffix)) (সহ:suffix))
```

Comment: @karu: Okay, but does my solution work for you? It looks like a good match to your requirement

Comment: @ Borodin I have some issues  here when there are mismatches অক্টোবর (অক্টোবর), this one for example . I just need to remove the above

Comment: @karu: That isn't a mismatch, it's an identity production. Your question only gave the translation of the last line as a requirement. Do you really need me to walk you home as well? If you have another question then submit it as a new post. Programming isn't about copying software from one site and posting it on another to get it changed. Please do some work of your own

Comment: I just mentioned the code fails to capture it. It doesn´t mean

Comment: @karu: Ah okay. So are you saying that my answer solves your question? If so then it helps to say so in the comments. You can wait a while -- days if you like -- to see if a better answer comes up